ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_sqlite3' django debian
me sale este error al tratar de ejecutar mi proyecto con python manage.py runserver

Watching for file changes with StatReloader Exception in thread
django-main-thread: Traceback (most recent call last):   File
"/usr/local/lib/python3.11/threading.py", line 1038, in
_bootstrap_inner
self.run()   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/threading.py", line 975, in run
self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)   File "/home/dsanchez/Música/django/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py",
line 64, in wrapper
fn(*args, **kwargs)   File "/home/dsanchez/Música/django/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py",
line 125, in inner_run
autoreload.raise_last_exception()   File "/home/dsanchez/Música/django/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py",
line 87, in raise_last_exception
raise _exception[1]   File "/home/dsanchez/Música/django/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/init.py",
line 394, in execute
autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()   File "/home/dsanchez/Música/django/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py",
line 64, in wrapper
fn(*args, **kwargs)   File "/home/dsanchez/Música/django/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/init.py",
line 24, in setup
apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)   File "/home/dsanchez/Música/django/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py",
line 116, in populate
app_config.import_models()   File "/home/dsanchez/Música/django/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/apps/config.py",
line 269, in import_models
self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/importlib/init.py", line 126, in
import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "", line 1206, in _gcd_import   File
"", line 1178, in _find_and_load   File
"", line 1149, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "", line 690, in _load_unlocked
File "", line 940, in
exec_module   File "", line 241, in
_call_with_frames_removed   File "/home/dsanchez/Música/django/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py",
line 3, in 
from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager   File
"/home/dsanchez/Música/django/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py",
line 59, in 
class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):   File "/home/dsanchez/Música/django/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py",
line 143, in new
new_class.add_to_class("_meta", Options(meta, app_label))   File "/home/dsanchez/Música/django/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py",
line 371, in add_to_class
value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)   File "/home/dsanchez/Música/django/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py",
line 243, in contribute_to_class
self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length()
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "/home/dsanchez/Música/django/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/connection.py",
line 15, in getattr
return getattr(self._connections[self._alias], item)
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "/home/dsanchez/Música/django/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/connection.py",
line 62, in getitem
conn = self.create_connection(alias)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "/home/dsanchez/Música/django/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/utils.py",
line 193, in create_connection
backend = load_backend(db["ENGINE"])
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "/home/dsanchez/Música/django/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/utils.py",
line 113, in load_backend
return import_module("%s.base" % backend_name)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/importlib/init.py", line 126, in
import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "/home/dsanchez/Música/django/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py",
line 10, in 
from sqlite3 import dbapi2 as Database   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/sqlite3/init.py", line 57, in 
from sqlite3.dbapi2 import *   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/sqlite3/dbapi2.py", line 27, in 
from _sqlite3 import * ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_sqlite3'


Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Necesitas tener instalado libsqlite3-dev (sudo apt-get install libsqlite3-dev) antes de instalar/configurar Python. Una vez instalado es posible que necesite reconfigurar/recompilar Python, pero te recomiendo encarecidamente no tocar en absoluto la instalación de Python que viene con cualquier distro Linux, muchísimas cosas del propio SO dependen de ella, alterarla puede terminar con el sistema entero roto si no sabes muy bien que haces.

Usa siempre entornos virtuales para tus proyectos y si necesitas instalar múltiples versiones de Python, pyenv es una opción muy simple. Esto te permite tener un entorno separado para cada proyecto, con su propia versión del Python y las dependencias del proyecto aisladas, dejando siempre intacta la instalación del sistema de Python.
